# How to use Lucene IKVMC port in .Net?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I just converted the Latest Lucene version(4.3.0) to Lucene.Net with IKVMC. When I am trying to open a file with `FSDirectory` its giving me the error `Only valid arguments Java.io.File`
Sample:

```
FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(fs);
```

How to give a Java file to a C# application?

Did IKVMC convert the JAR file?

Can I use the converted DLL version in .Net?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just using Lucene.NET?

Comment: I wanted to use the Latest Lucene(4.3.0) in which the boolean query problem is fixed.Also, the official Lucene.Net is very old now. The newest Lucene.Net version is 3.0.3 where as the newest Lucene.Jar is 4.3.0

Comment: Can you comment on what "boolean query problem" you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C# project add references to

```
lucene-core.4.3.0.dll (created by ikvmc) 
IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll (from ikvm/bin folder)
```

then in your C# code

```
 //use java.io.File from IKVM.OpenJDK.Core
 var file = new java.io.File(path);            
 var dir = FSDirectory.open(file);
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a ton. So, this way I can even use Java Commands in C#?

Comment: @John 'Java Commands' - what do you mean? I think if ikvm is able to generate correct .NET code then other java libs/classes can be used in .NET. But need to test every particular case.